# Hyperbolic trigonometric functions identity

Tags: calculus, hyperbolic-functions

$$\cosh(\sinh^{-1}x) = \sqrt{x^{2}+1}$$

I used the fact that $\cosh(x) = \frac{1}{2}(e^{x}+e^{-x})$

and that $\sinh^{-1}(x) = \ln(x + \sqrt{x^{2}+1})$

Eventually I simplified to

$$\frac{x^{2}+x\sqrt{x^{2}+1}+1}{x+ \sqrt{x^{2}+1}}$$

I verified and so far I am correct, but I can't see how I can simplify further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the top is $\sqrt{x^2+1}\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)$.

**Remark**: You may have worked too hard by first obtaining a formula for $\sinh^{-1}x$, though such a formula is in fact useful.

For we have $\cosh^2 t-\sin^2 t=1$ for all $t$. Let $t=\sinh^{-1}(x)$. We get $\cosh^2 t=1+x^2$. But $\cosh t$ is always positive, so $\cosh t=\sqrt{1+x^2}$.

Comment: Thank you! That is a good way of looking at it.

Comment: You are welcome.